# How should I write bndstx/bndldx in the masm assembly source code?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, masm

I have tried such a source code with masm as the following.
But all ones have failed.

```
    ; https://fossies.org/linux/nasm/test/mpx.asm
    
    ; bndstx
    bndstx [eax+ebx*1+0x3], bnd0    ;missing operator in expression
    ;bndstx [eax+0x3,ebx], bnd0 ;error
    ;bndstx [eax+0x3], bnd0, ebx    ;error
    ;bndstx [eax+0x3], ebx, bnd0    ;error
    ;bndstx [ecx*1], bnd2       ;instruction operand must have size
    ;bndstx [,ecx*1], bnd27     ;error
    ;bndstx [0,ecx*1], bnd2     ;error
    ;bndstx [0], bnd2, ecx      ;has three operands 
    ;bndstx [0], ecx, bnd2      ;has three operands 
    bndstx [edx+0x399], bnd3    ;missing operator in expression
    ;bndstx [1*ebx+3], bnd2     ;instruction operand must have size
    ;bndstx [3,1*ebx], bnd2     ;syntax error : ,
    ;bndstx [3], ebx, bnd2      ;syntax error : ,
    ;bndstx [edx], bnd1     ;instruction operand must have size

    ; bndldx
    bndldx bnd0, [eax+ebx*1+0x3]    ;missing operator in expression
    ;bndldx bnd2, [ebx+edx+3]   ;invalid instruction operands
    ;bndldx bnd2, [ecx*1]       ;invalid instruction operands
    bndldx bnd3, [edx+0x399]    ;missing operator in expression
    ;bndldx bnd2, [1*ebx+3]     ;invalid instruction operands
    ;bndldx bnd2, [3], ebx      ;syntax error : ,
    ;bndldx bnd1, [edx]     ;invalid instruction operands
```

```
;https://www.intel.cn/content/dam/develop/external/us/en/documents/intel-mpx-enablingguide.pdf
    bndstx [rdx], rax, bnd0 ;error
    bndldx rax, bnd0, [rdx] ;error
```

- BNDSTX — Store Extended Bounds Using Address Translation

```
    NP 0F 1B /r
    BNDSTX mib, bnd
```

Store the bounds in bnd and the pointer value in the index register
of mib to a bound table entry (BTE) with address translation using
the base of mib.

```
base := mib.SIB.base ? mib.SIB.base + Disp: 0;
ptr_value := mib.SIB.index ? mib.SIB.index : 0;

*In 64-bit Mode
A_BDE[63:0] := (Zero_extend64(base[47+MAWA:20] « 3) + (BNDCFG[63:12] «12 ); 1
A_BT[63:0] := LoadFrom(A_BDE);
IF A_BT[0] equal 0 Then
BNDSTATUS := A_BDE | 02H;
#BR;
FI;
A_DEST[63:0] := (Zero_extend64(base[19:3] « 5) + (A_BT[63:3] « 3 ); // address of Bound table entry
A_DEST[16][63:0] := ptr_value;
A_DEST[0][63:0] := BND.LB;
A_DEST[8][63:0] := BND.UB;
```

- BNDLDX — Load Extended Bounds Using Address Translation

```
    NP 0F 1A /r
    BNDLDX bnd, mib
```

Load the bounds stored in a bound table entry (BTE) into bnd with
address translation using the base of mib and conditional on the
index of mib matching the pointer value in the BTE.

```
base := mib.SIB.base ? mib.SIB.base + Disp: 0;
ptr_value := mib.SIB.index ? mib.SIB.index : 0;

*In 64-bit Mode
A_BDE[63:0] := (Zero_extend64(base[47+MAWA:20] « 3) + (BNDCFG[63:12] «12 ); 1
A_BT[63:0] := LoadFrom(A_BDE);
IF A_BT[0] equal 0 Then
BNDSTATUS := A_BDE | 02H;
#BR;
FI;
A_BTE[63:0] := (Zero_extend64(base[19:3] « 5) + (A_BT[63:3] « 3 );
Temp_lb[63:0] := LoadFrom(A_BTE);
Temp_ub[63:0] := LoadFrom(A_BTE + 8);
Temp_ptr[63:0] := LoadFrom(A_BTE + 16);
IF Temp_ptr equal ptr_value Then
BND.LB := Temp_lb;
BND.UB := Temp_ub;
ELSE
BND.LB := 0;
BND.UB := 0;
FI;
```

- bnd = A 128-bit bounds register. BND0 through BND3.
- mib = SIB-addressing form of the memory operand.
  A memory operand using SIB addressing form, where the index register is not used in address calculation, Scale is ignored. Only the base and displacement are used in effective address calculation.

I want to know how to write the instruction bndstx/bndldx in the masm assembly source code.

I have been making my original assembler nwsa support new intel instructions now.

- PS1, 2023/07/22, 18:27, JPN
  I succeeded by writing the following.
  (Only the latter one is Ok.)

```
    ;BNDSTX Dword ptr [EAX+ECX], BND0 ;invalid operand size for instrcution
    BNDSTX Qword ptr [EAX+ECX], BND0 ;OK
```

- PS2, I found the following one is also OK :

```
BNDLDX BND0, Qword ptr [EAX+ECX]
```

```
 00000469  67& 0F 1B 04         BNDSTX Qword ptr [EAX+ECX], BND0
       08
 0000046E  0F 1B 04 08          BNDSTX Qword ptr [RAX+RCX], BND0
                    
 00000472  67& 0F 1A 04         BNDLDX BND0, Qword ptr [EAX+ECX]
       08
 00000477  0F 1A 04 08          BNDLDX BND0, Qword ptr [RAX+RCX]
```

- PS3, I rewrote 0x03-->03h, 0x399-->399h and add "qword ptr" as a type.

```
    ;bndstx [eax+ebx*1+03h], bnd0   ;instruction operand must have size
    bndstx qword ptr [eax+ebx*1+03h], bnd0  ;OK
    bndstx [eax+03h,ebx], bnd0  ;syntax error : ,
    bndstx [eax+03h], bnd0, ebx ;syntax error : ,
    bndstx [eax+03h], ebx, bnd0 ;syntax error : ,
    bndstx qword ptr [ecx*1], bnd2  ;OK
    bndstx [,ecx*1], bnd27      ;syntax error : ,
    bndstx [0,ecx*1], bnd2      ;syntax error : ,
    bndstx [0], bnd2, ecx       ;syntax error : ,
    bndstx [0], ecx, bnd2       ;syntax error : ,
    bndstx qword ptr [edx+399h], bnd3   ;OK
    bndstx qword ptr [1*ebx+3], bnd2    ;OK
    bndstx [3,1*ebx], bnd2      ;syntax error : ,
    bndstx [3], ebx, bnd2       ;syntax error : ,
    bndstx qword ptr [edx], bnd1    ;OK

    ; bndldx
    bndldx bnd0, [eax+ebx*1+03h]    ;invalid instruction operands
    bndldx bnd2, [ebx+edx+3]    ;invalid instruction operands
    bndldx bnd2, [ecx*1]        ;invalid instruction operands
    bndldx bnd3, [edx+399h]     ;invalid instruction operands
    bndldx bnd2, [1*ebx+3]      ;invalid instruction operands
    bndldx bnd2, [3], ebx       ;syntax error : ,
    bndldx bnd1, [edx]      ;invalid instruction operands
```

was assembled as the following :

```
                    ; bndstx
                    ;bndstx [eax+ebx*1+03h], bnd0   ;instruction operand must have size
 00000469  67& 0F 1B 44/        bndstx qword ptr [eax+ebx*1+03h], bnd0  ;OK
       18 03
                    bndstx [eax+03h,ebx], bnd0  ;syntax error : ,
test2.asm(310) : error A2008:syntax error : ,
                    bndstx [eax+03h], bnd0, ebx ;syntax error : ,
test2.asm(311) : error A2008:syntax error : ,
                    bndstx [eax+03h], ebx, bnd0 ;syntax error : ,
test2.asm(312) : error A2008:syntax error : ,
 0000046F  67& 0F 1B 14         bndstx qword ptr [ecx*1], bnd2  ;OK
       0D 00 00 00 00
                    bndstx [,ecx*1], bnd27      ;syntax error : ,
test2.asm(314) : error A2008:syntax error : ,
                    bndstx [0,ecx*1], bnd2      ;syntax error : ,
test2.asm(315) : error A2008:syntax error : ,
                    bndstx [0], bnd2, ecx       ;syntax error : ,
test2.asm(316) : error A2008:syntax error : ,
                    bndstx [0], ecx, bnd2       ;syntax error : ,
test2.asm(317) : error A2008:syntax error : ,
 00000478  67& 0F 1B 9A         bndstx qword ptr [edx+399h], bnd3   
       031D00000399
 00000480  67& 0F 1B 14         bndstx qword ptr [1*ebx+3], bnd2    
       1D 03 00 00 00
                    bndstx [3,1*ebx], bnd2      ;syntax error : ,
test2.asm(320) : error A2008:syntax error : ,
                    bndstx [3], ebx, bnd2       ;syntax error : ,
test2.asm(321) : error A2008:syntax error : ,
 00000489  67& 0F 1B 0A         bndstx qword ptr [edx], bnd1    

                    ; bndldx
                    bndldx bnd0, [eax+ebx*1+03h]    ;invalid instruction operands
test2.asm(325) : error A2070:invalid instruction operands
                    bndldx bnd2, [ebx+edx+3]    ;invalid instruction operands
test2.asm(326) : error A2070:invalid instruction operands
                    bndldx bnd2, [ecx*1]        ;invalid instruction operands
test2.asm(327) : error A2070:invalid instruction operands
                    bndldx bnd3, [edx+399h]     ;invalid instruction operands
test2.asm(328) : error A2070:invalid instruction operands
                    bndldx bnd2, [1*ebx+3]      ;invalid instruction operands
test2.asm(329) : error A2070:invalid instruction operands
                    bndldx bnd2, [3], ebx       ;syntax error : ,
test2.asm(330) : error A2008:syntax error : ,
                    bndldx bnd1, [edx]      ;invalid instruction operands
test2.asm(331) : error A2070:invalid instruction operands
```

Comment: Note that MPX is deprecated by Intel and no longer supported in later CPUs. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_MPX says it's already removed from 2019 hardware and later.

Comment: Sounds like you've already figured it out for `bndstx`: you say `bndstx qword ptr [eax+ebx*1+03h], bnd0  ;OK` assembles ok with MASM.  Without the `qword ptr`, it's also accepted by NASM.  (NASM rejects either `qword` or `dword` size overrides with `bndstx`, though, since it's actually a 12 or 24-byte store if I'm reading the docs right, depending on mode).

Comment: If you're writing your own assembler, you could invent your own syntax for encoding the addressing mode, which splits them up since they don't have the usual meaning. But you asked about MASM syntax, which uses addressing-mode syntax like `[eax + ebx*1 + 03h]` or `3[eax + ebx*1]`.  IDK why you're trying to put commas inside square brackets, and I wouldn't expect extra operands to work, since the `bndstx/ldx` instructions are designed to use the normal ModRM encoding but assign different meanings to base and index.